# How can I create a file from a byte array and send it to the stream as a file without creating this file on the disk?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a file from a byte array and send it directly to the stream as a file without creating this file on the disk?

Comment: You can easily send a byte array to a memory stream.

Comment: When you say "Send it to the stream, what do you mean ? Is it in the context of an asp.net application, and you want the user to download it ?

Comment: Please write your complete use case. You can write bytes to stream, then whats next?

Comment: do you want to send the file as an attachment?

Comment: I want to save it in database as a file. Per my understand  and checks  - the streaming a file is much more faster, then streaming an array. Please correct me, if i am wrong. Can you explain please - what is sending as an attachment? Thank you.

Comment: You can't save a file format to a database.  You save a byte array to the database.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) class that takes a byteArray as argument. You don't need to write a file.

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

Alternatively, you can [`Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.write.aspx) to an existing `MemoryStream`:

```
memStream.Write(byteArray, 0 , byteArray.Length);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @LoenidB If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear. You are asking to "create a file" and yet you are saying "without creating this file on disk". However it is possible to either "create a file from a byte array" :

```
File.WriteAllBytes( path, bytes );
```

where path is the filename to create and bytes is the byte[] to write - this is just one of those many ways.

Or "send to a stream without creating file on disk". ie: Write to MemoryStream:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream( bytes );
```

I am afraid your question needs to be more specific on what you are trying to do.

Edit: Crypto sample:

```
private static byte[] Crypt
  (byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv, ICryptoTransform cryptor)
{
  MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
  using( Stream c = new CryptoStream(m, cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write ))
  {
    c.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  }
  return m.ToArray();
}

public static byte[] Encrpyt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
  using( Aes algorithm = Aes.Create())
  using( ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key,iv))
  {
    return Crypt( data, key, iv, encryptor );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a file. I am sending this file to encryption class. This encryption class returning byte[]. I can create this encrypted file on the disk c:\temp\test.file from this array and after that stream it to wherever i want as a file. But i don't want create this test.file on the disk, because if i want to encrypt 1MB - I need 2MB space on the disk (i know, that i can delete this file from temp after streaming), but if i want to encrypt 10GB file - i need temporary 20GB free space on the disk. That why i don't want to create it as a file on the disk. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean but added a crypto sample anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example! What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: What I don't understand is what you are trying to do + why would encryting a file would double its size (BTW your encryption stream could also be a stream from Compression namespace).

Comment: can i use it to encrypt big files?

Comment: I think so. You should try.